# Magento 2 + php 7.0.5 Compilation Fails in Production Mode

Tags: magento2, php-7, compilation

I'm having some issues running the compilation process (either single and multi tenant) with magento 2.0.2~4 running over ubuntu 14.04 & php 7.0.5 `(PHP 7.0.5-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1)`.

I can run any magento-console process without problem (install/uninstall/upgrade/flush cache etc) but `setup:di:compile` and `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant`.

The process finish as usual, no log, no error output, no nothing but after that I can't run the magento-console anymore since the compiler generates an empty serialized string (`{}`) in `var/di/relations.ser` then magento can't find the DI definition for `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface` and throws:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface in /var/www/magento2/src/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73
```

Any Idea?

Comment: sounds like a php extension missing to me. what do you get when you run composer install? Also make sure that you never use the "no-dev" flag as it has a known bug with magento2

Comment: Hi @ClaudiuCreanga Thanks for comment, I'm not using composer at "deploy level" I've tried both composer generated and packaged (downloading .tar.gz) versions, but seems to be a bug with the php version: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4070 - BTW: all needed php extension are installed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a **known bug with Magento 2 and PHP 7.0.5**, you can keep an eye on the issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4070

Comment: Thanks! I saw the bug report on github a few minutes after I'd written this question. I'm following it now.

Comment: @MauroNigrele feel free to mark the question as answered so it will help other people with the same problem ;)

Comment: Is there a workaround for this issue?